# Top Nav moves up when clicking on md-menu, mdDialog buttons

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm creating an angularjs and asp.net site that uses angular material, and when you scroll on the page and click an mdDialog or an md-menu the top nav will go up the body or "disappear". Here's the css for the top nav

```
.sidebar-header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #ffffff;
padding: 0 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
z-index: 998;}
```

and  [here's the html code when the top nav disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbyP.png)

any suggestions would help, I have no idea how to fix this bug at the moment.

**EDIT**

The js fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7g9peo6s/49/)

Comment: can you please post jsfiddle example here?

Comment: Edited my post with the js fiddle now @VikasJadhav

Comment: you mean when md menu  opens body scroll disappear right?

Comment: body scroll do you mean like I wont be able to scroll the body? that's a minor problem, my main problem is that the top nav gets pushed up to the top of the body because of angular material changing the top attribute in css

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for anyone who has the same bug as me this is my fix:

in jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            console.log($(window).scrollTop());
            var topPixel = $(window).scrollTop();
            var sideNavHeaderPixelCount = topPixel - topPixel;

            $("<enter top nav identifier here>").css("top", sideNavHeaderPixelCount);
        });
    });
```

in css:

```
#menu_container_0{
    top: 52px !important;
}
```

so I just played around with it until I Found a pattern. if the top offset of the body after clicking on an md-menu is -137.5px then you just need to get the decimal and use that as the top for your top nav (top: .5px). also the #menu_container_0 is the Id of the md-menu I used in my top nav, I didn't want it to overlap.